# MySQL is not updating when running this query

Tags: mysql

```
load data infile "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/newdata.csv" 
into table prodlookupfile
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

This executes but the new data is NOT uploaded into the table in MySQL, what am I missing?

Comment: Make sure that the data in CSV file are `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

Comment: the data transferred into the columns when i ran the table data import wizard, but when i try to run this query to bring in additional data it wont execute.

Comment: Does `show warnings;` right after the load data (in the same session) tell you anything helpful?

Comment: the warning is Error Code: 1261. Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns

Comment: Can you [upload a screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67362363/edit) for a few data rows of the csv?